# Making Twig filter to assign defaults unless otherwise specified

Tags: php, templates, twig, code-readability

I'm trying to use twig as a template system for my website. I'm wanting to write something along the lines of...

```
{{ title }}
{% pageAuthor | Unknown %}
```

I would like "Unknown" to become the default value if pageAuthor is empty. I could use a bunch of "if" statements but that would hurt readability. This is clean and easy to write. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Twig's `default` filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/default.html):

```
{{ pageAuthor|default('Unknown') }}
```